# Excel Previous Number in column that does not match current

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zCXg.png)

[image]

I would like help with a formula that can look in previous cells and return a number that does not match current.

Example

Row     Numbers  Formula

1   -----       10      ----    0

2      ----    20    ------     10

3    -----      20     -----    10

4    -----      30      -----   20

5      -----    30      -----   20

Please help describe a formula that if I was on the fifth row in the 3rd column it would return the value 20 as the previous number in column 2 that does not match number 30.

Thanks

I included a screen shot to help illustrate what i need.

Comment: So is the `0,10,20` arbitrary, is it a pattern(add 10 when it changes),or is it the number(10,20,30) minus the original(10)?

Comment: 0,10,20 is arbitrary, I have thousands of rows that use between 10 through 99 as a grade, the formula I would like help with needs to return the grade prior to the one currently on.

Comment: Then as I understand it my formula below will work.

Answer (score 3):

This will return the previous number every time the number changes:

```
=IF(B3<>B2,B2,C2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(ROW()-1<1,"0",IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),1))=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,1)),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,2)),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,1))))
```

This is one way to do it.  I was confused by your use of the word previous, when you meant "most recent different number"

Try to ask for help rather than say "I need."  Show us what you have tried and we can help you refine your answer.

Comment: (1) Aside for explicitly handling Row 1, and the fact that you assumed that the row numbers are *just* the row numbers (and not an actual column), this is equivalent to [Scott Craner’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1432678/354511#1432699).  See Scott’s answer for the more idiomatic way of doing this.  (2) Why do you specify the Row 1 value as being the string ```"0"``` and not the integer ```0```?

Comment: Yes the answers are similar.  I did answer 17 minutes before Scott.  Yes I did treat this as if the data was in column A.  (2) I should have left off the quotes to keep the 0 as a numeral.